# Which consumer API to use for kafka 0.10.1?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I am new to Kafka and I have a  Kafka leader `version 0.10.0` and a zookeeper `version 3.4.6`.There is two type of Kafka consumer API that I came across:

```
1. Kafka Polling
2. Kafka Streams
```

I am not able to find the significant difference between these two. What is the difference between Kafka polling and Kafka streaming consumers?What are the use cases suitable to both?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KafkaStreams:
KafkaStreams is used to do computation on data from one topic and send computed data to other topic.
Internally kafkaStreams use Producer and Consumer both.

KafkaPolling :
Kafka polling in kafka consumer fetches data from topic and its part of consumer process.

From my point of view if you just want to consume data from a topic, go for kafka consumer, else if you want to do some computation and save it for further use, use kafka streams.

Comment: If we want to write map reduce jobs with Kafka then which API should I use?

Comment: @Abhimanyu: You can't write MapReduce jobs / batch processing jobs with Kafka.  Kafka is a streaming platform to write (notably real-time) stream processing applications, not a batch processing system like Hadoop.